# Heroku Mailgun account activation

Tags: heroku, mailgun

I have a Heroku account and am using the Mailgun add-on. I have verified my domain, however, I need to activate the Mailgun account via email confirmation. The email account which is supposed to have received the email is at app[numbers]@heroku.com. I am not aware of how I might access that email. There is a link to resend email or update email address, however the update form instructs me to change setting in Heroku's dashboard, where I see no reference to that address. I am sure I am missing something simple, but am at a loss.

Comment: Hi there, could you share some information on how you managed to verify the domain. The steps taken, etc.

Comment: I just followed the steps in the [documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-sending.html#verify-your-domain) for that part. I will admit I was reloading the webpage thinking it would check automatically, but you have to press the verify button on the interface.